# ValueError: malformed string using ast.literal_eval

Tags: python, json, string, python-requests, malformed

I'm doing a loop to get json api, here is what I have in my loop:

```
response_item = requests.request('GET',url_item,params=None,verify=False)
response_item = json.loads(response_item.text)
response_item = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(response_item, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))
```

I scan around 45000 json objects, I generate "url_item" variable for each iteration. Each object is the same, I can get something like 7000 object and I have the following error when I reach the 7064th:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\tools\api_item.py", line 47, in <module>
    response_item = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(response_item, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

I used to print the second and third "response_item". Of course in this case the third one isn't displayed since I have the error just before, here what I have for the print after the json.load:

```
{u'restrictions': [], u'name': u'Sac \xe0 dos de base', u'level': 0, u'rarity': u'Basic', u'vendor_value': 11, u'details': {u'no_sell_or_sort': False, u'size': 20}, u'game_types': [u'Activity', u'Wvw', u'Dungeon', u'Pve'], u'flags': [u'NoSell', u'SoulbindOnAcquire', u'SoulBindOnUse'], u'icon': u'https://render.guildwars2.com/file/80E36806385691D4C0910817EF2A6C2006AEE353/61755.png', u'type': u'Bag', u'id': 8932, u'description': u'Un sac de 20 emplacements pour les personnages d\xe9butants.'}
```

Every item I get before this one has the same type, same format, and I don't have any error except for the 7064th !

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you using `ast.literal_eval()` on the output of `json.dumps()` in the first place?

Comment: is it recommended to use `output = json.dumps(json.load(fdobject))` instead of `ast.literal_eval` ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should **not** use `ast.literal_eval()` on JSON data. JSON and Python literals may *look* like the same thing, but they are very much not.

In this case, your data contains a boolean flag, set to `false` in JSON. A proper Python boolean uses title-case, so `False`:

```
>>> import json, ast
>>> s = '{"no_sell_or_sort": false, "size": 20}'
>>> json.loads(s)
{u'no_sell_or_sort': False, u'size': 20}
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Other differences include using `null` instead of `None`, and Unicode escape sequences in what to Python 2 looks like a *plain (bytes) string*, using UTF-16 surrogates when escaping non-BMP codepoints.

Load your data with `json.loads()`, not `ast.literal_eval()`. Not only will it handle proper JSON just fine, it is also *faster*.

In your case, it appears you are using `json.dumps()` then try to load the data again with `ast.literal_eval()`. There is **no need** for that step, you **already** had a Python object.

In other words, the line:

```
response_item = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(response_item, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))
```

is redundant at best, and very, very wrong, at worst. Re-encoding `response_item` to a JSON string does not produce something that can be interpreted as a Python literal.

Comment: And safer, might I add.

Comment: @Kroltan: `ast.literal_eval()` is perfectly safe. It parses the string to an abstract syntax tree, then only maps literals (strings, lists, numbers, etc) to Python objects. Everything else raises an exception.

Comment: I've deleted the line with ast.literal_eval() as you told me. Now I don't have the error, but I have something with unicode characters "u'" , I've tried manythings to remove those characters because they are inserted in database then. That's the eason why I added the line with ast..

Comment: @Aurélien: All JSON data is *Unicode* data. If you see `u` prefixes show up in your database, you have a different problem there, where you are inserting `repr(value)` into the database rather that `value` itself.

Comment: @Aurélien: You need to fix that code; the problem lies there, not here in how you load the data.

Comment: @Aurélien: Perhaps you can post a *new* question with a sample of how you insert your data into the database. `u'...'` objects are Python Unicode text objects, the prefix is there to distinguish the type from Python bytestrings.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I import json via csv in my database, so do I will have a look to convert to utf8 in csv file or in database

Answer (score -4):

ast.literal_eval is safe with SQL injection if you are using this.
because when an unwanted charter is inserted it will show Syntex error which prevents from an injection.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL injection. And SQL injection relies on string *contents*, not types.

Comment: Note to reviewers: This shouldn't have been flagged as Very Low Quality in the first place because the VLQ queue is not for technical inaccuracies - that's what downvoting and comments are for. This is already downvoted with a comment explaining why it's incorrect, so no further action is needed on it.

Comment: So click looks ok in the review queue.